# How to change method indexer to properties of indexer?

Tags: c#

```
public ArrayList choiceArray = new ArrayList();
public UC_RadioX Item(int index)
        {
            return (UC_RadioX)choiceArray[index];
        }
```

When I used:

```
    cc.Item(0).Checked = true;
    cc.Item(1).Checked = true;
```

How to change method to properties?

Answer (score 2):

You can define [Indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) in the following way:

```
// ...
public ArrayList choiceArray = new ArrayList();
public UC_RadioX this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        return (UC_RadioX)choiceArray[index];
    }
}
// ...
```

That  will allow you to use the `[]` notation on the class instance itself:

```
cc[0].Checked = true;
cc[1].Checked = true;
```

Comment: Can change to this

cc.Item[0].Checked = true;

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx

Based on your reply to another answer, I think you could more easily do what you're trying to do with the property `public List<UC_RadioX> Item { get;set;}` then, you'd be directly accessing a UC_RadioX object, and you can access it via indexer.  This will work in C# 2.0 and higher. The auto-implemented property `{get;set;}` is C# 3.0 and higher.

Accessing these items within an object instantiated as `cc` can be done like:

```
UC_RadioX rx = cc.Item[0];
bool good = cc.Item[1].checked;
```

Comment: Also, the common practice is to pluralize collection names. I assume, though, that you're trying to change current code as little as possible.